# understanding autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, visualforce

What does this mean in jquery autocomplete? :

```
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
```

I understand that the autocomplete choices show up in the tags div.
I am trying to apply a salesforce visualforce generated id to this script.

So in salesforce, the id is auto generated. So If I say the id = 'tags', in salesforce it becomes j0_jd1:j2_jd3:tags.

Has anyone overcome using autocomplete with visualforce ids?

Comment: What's wrong with not using an id, but using a class?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('[id$=tags]').autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
});
```